# Receive 400 (Bad request) when call ajax using method POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

My ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getUserName",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: ({
            email : email
        }),
        success: function(res) {
            $("#user a").text(res.data);
        }
    });
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserName", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String getUserName(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email) {
    String name = userService.getUserName(email);
    return "{\"data\": \"" + name + "\"}";
}
```

If I use method GET, controller returns data normally. But when I use POST, I get 400 bad request error.

Can anybody explain to me this case and how to fix it?

Comment: I think '@RequestParam' is used for GET and DELETE requests and '@RequestBody' is used for POST.

Answer (score 0):

Remove parenthesis in your data section

```
 data: {
            email : email
        },
```

Comment: It didn't work. I fixed it by using `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`.Thank for helping anyway.